# AutoCAD Civil3d 2023 C# .net - Property-Set define who has experience with that?

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

I work with AutoCAD Civil3d 2023.
There I have the possibility to define Property-sets.
I want to define property-sets with a module because I have too much sets to define manually.

Now I try to build a dll with vscode and dotnet 4.8 to generate and manage Property-Sets in Civil 3d. The first try to make my own commands works fine. But who can tell me which way I can access or generate property-sets?

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.Civil.DatabaseServices.Styles;
namespace AU.KO_WT_TestPlugin
{

public class Initialization : IExtensionApplication
{

    [CommandMethod("Pset")]
    public void SetPropertySet()
    {
    Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        ed.WriteMessage("\nPset erstellt.");

    }
    void IExtensionApplication.Initialize()
    {
    }

    void IExtensionApplication.Terminate()
    {
    }
}
}
```

This code works fine and I can use the netload command to load the dll file to civil3d. But I don't understand which way I have to go to define a property-set.

Who can help me please?